# App to keep track of communications with contacts

Tags: android, crm, contact-manager

I'm hunting for a phone app to help me keep track of my contacts.  In particular I'm looking to:

- keep notes about any and every contact on my phone.
- categorise contacts with arbitrary labels
- identify contacts in each category who have not been contacted for a while

I'd like this to integrate with my Android contacts and so do the above with any and every contact.

My overall aim is to keep in touch with folk more easily.

I note that most social networking apps now do the exact opposite of what I'm after: they only show me the people I've contacted recently.